# Unable to load asm dll to c#

Tags: c#, assembly, dll, fasm

I have created a dll on fasm and want to run it from c#. However, when I try, I get an error

> System.DllNotFoundException: "Unable to load DLL "Project.dll ": Invalid attempt to access the memory address. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E6)"

here is my code

```
format   PE gui dll                 ; собираем DLL-модуль
include 'win32ax.inc'               ; макросы для укороченных директив
include 'encoding/win1251.inc'      ; подключим кирилицу
.data
mes0    db  'Библиотека Dll удачно поключена!',0      ; мессага-флаг, что DLL робит
wName   db  'Тест внешнего модуля',0                  ;  ..обзовём окно.

.code
start:                    ; точка входа!
   mov     eax,1      ; возвращаем TRUE
   ret                ;  ..в родитель LdrLoadDLL()
proc   Hello
   invoke  MessageBox,0,mes0,wName,0   ; даём о себе знать!
   ret                                 ; на выход.
endp                                       ; конец процедуры 'Hello'

.end start                ; макрос автоматом вставит секцию импорта.

section '.edata' export data readable      ;
export  'myDll.dll',\                      ; имя нашей библиотеки
     Hello, 'Hello'                    ; тут перечисляем имена всех процедур 
section '.reloc' fixups data discardable
```

c#

```
internal class Program
{
    [DllImport("Project.dll")] public static extern void Hello();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Hello();
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide the compiler command you use to compile your asm file.

Comment: @ПМФ FASM.EXE ./Main.asm

Comment: This is Windows error 998 (aka 0x3E6), a nasty mishap.  Happens when the DllMain() function of a DLL fails with an AccessViolation.  There is no DllMain() function in the snippet, but there's `.end start`.  That sets the entrypoint for the module, in other words DllMain(), not what you want to do.  Replace with `.end`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `.reloc` section needs to be `readable`; change it to:

```
section '.reloc' fixups data readable discardable
```

You may also need to add a dummy entry after it:

```
if $=$$
    dd 0,8  ; if there are no fixups, generate dummy entry
end if
```

Or use this instead:

```
data fixups
end data
```

Also make sure to compile your C# project for the right architecture (32-bit x86), and not AnyCpu.

The last thing you might need to fix is the character encoding. I was able to do this by using `MessageBoxW` and [`du`](https://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=win32#1.9) instead of `db`, but you may be able to get it to work with `MessageBoxA` if you specify the encoding somewhere. Make sure the encoding of the asm file matches the included encoding file.