# creating a dll on fasm

Tags: c#, fasm

I want to create a dll on fasm, with a function that adds two non-negative numbers, and also checks the sum for overflow. However, my simple code doesn't work. When I try to call the dll, I get an error saying that the dll is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

```
    format   PE gui dll
include 'win32ax.inc'
include 'encoding/win1251.inc'


.data
mes0    db  'Библиотека Dll удачно поключена!',0 
wName   db  'Тест внешнего модуля',0

.code
start:
       mov     eax,1
       ret


proc   Hello
       invoke  MessageBox,0,mes0,wName,0 
       ret 
endp

.end start


section '.edata' export data readable
export  'myDll.dll',\
         Hello, 'Hello'

section '.reloc' fixups data discardable
```

Comment: And why you tagged your post with `C#`?

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper to be honest, I use c# as the language from which I call the dll

Comment: I will assume your DLL is called 'myDll.dll' and you called the function correctly from C# (as you have not provided that code).

Is your C# project target set to x86?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load asm dll to c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72423925/unable-to-load-asm-dll-to-c-sharp)